Firebase onCall Functions Blocked by CORS, tried as true, with links, as false
Yes there are hundreds of post already about this, I've tried every solution. And it's still not working.
I have onCall firebase functions working fine locally, but not when deployed to staging.
I have tried all of these options, { cors: false },, { cors: true },, { cors: ["/https://example\.appspot.com/"] }, and { cors: ["https://example.appspot.com"] }
Setup like this
const { onCall, HttpsError } = require('firebase-functions/v2/https');
const { initializeApp, cert } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getFirestore, FieldValue } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
const { getAuth } = require('firebase-admin/auth');

initializeApp();
...

exports.currentSSOPartners = onCall(
    { cors: false },
    async (request) => {

Every one of these options results in the error

Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-example.cloudfunctions.net/currentSSOPartners' from origin 'https://example.appspot.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:

I've also tried adding the invoker as discussed here, I've searched all 6 pages of results on github of people using cors with onCall functions, and I tried all of those solutions and no matter what I do, I'm blocked.
Sorry again for posting this, but I'm not sure what else to do.

You shouldn't have to configure anything related to CORS with callable functions.  It should be handled automatically by both the client and backend SDKs.  The documentation says "By default, callable functions have CORS configured to allow requests from all origins."  If this is not the case, then file an issue on GitHub with your steps to reproduce, including both client and server code.

What is the URL of the webpage that you are on when you attempt to call that onCall() ?  Also, check the OPTIONS (preflight) request in your browser's DevTools NETWORK tab that happens just before the network call for the onCall and see what its results are.
